# Why is the closed surface integral $\iint_A \phi\cdot\nabla \phi$ equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble proving that the following closed surface integral:
$$ \iint_A \phi \cdot\nabla \phi \, \mathrm dA = 0. 
$$
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear if $\phi$ is a scalar or a vector but regardless the answer will look something like this. Integration by parts says
$$
\int_A\phi\cdot\nabla\phi dA = \int_{\partial A}(\mathrm{stuff}) ds - \int_A\nabla\phi\cdot\phi dA.
$$
Since $A$ is the boundary of a closed surface, $\partial A=\emptyset$, so the middle integral is $0$ and
$$
\int_A\phi\cdot\nabla\phi dA=-\int_A\nabla\phi\cdot\phi dA=-\int_A\phi\cdot\nabla\phi dA,
$$
So $\int_A\phi\cdot\nabla\phi dA=0$.

The exact terms inside the middle integral depend on whether $\phi$ is a vector or scalar but the integral is $0$ regardless.

Comment: Sorry I am not exactly sure how integration by parts would work for the surface integral. In my case, phi is a scalar function.

Comment: There are several results that all look like integration by parts that depend on the exact structure and dimension of the integrand. Just to clarify, is $\nabla\phi$ being dotted with any normal vector or is this integral vector valued?

Comment: the gradient of phi is dotted with the the vector dA, which points normal to the surface.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to apply of one of these results https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions with $\Omega = A$ and $\Gamma = \emptyset$